# Associations for statistics

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and I need some help with associations. I'm using rails 6.0.3.4 and ruby 2.7.0.

Users can create cases and cases belongs to a certain district. Districts belongs to a state. It has to be that way, because cases can't belongs to a state.

Now I want to show the number of cases for a certain diagnosis for each state. I have to use district, to get all the cases for a state. How should I build the where(...) condition?

```
<!-- State -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">State</h5>
        <p><%= State.find(1).titel%> (<%= @diagnosis.cases.where(...).count %>)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

*My Models*

**case.rb**

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :set_pseud
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :diagnosis
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :report, optional: true
end
```

**district.rb**

```
class District < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :cases
  has_many :reports
  belongs_to :state
end
```

**state.rb**

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :districts
  has_many :users
end
```

---

For better understanding my **schema.rb**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_02_11_140244) do

  create_table "cases", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "gender"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.string "place_of_residence"
    t.string "diagnosis"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "diagnosis_id"
    t.bigint "district_id"
    t.bigint "report_id"
    t.string "pseud"
    t.index ["diagnosis_id"], name: "index_cases_on_diagnosis_id"
    t.index ["district_id"], name: "index_cases_on_district_id"
    t.index ["pseud"], name: "index_cases_on_pseud"
    t.index ["report_id"], name: "index_cases_on_report_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_cases_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "diagnoses", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "illness"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "districts", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "place"
    t.integer "postal_code"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "state_id", null: false
    t.index ["state_id"], name: "index_districts_on_state_id"
  end

  create_table "reports", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "district_id"
    t.text "comment"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["district_id"], name: "index_reports_on_district_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reports_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "states", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "titel"
    t.string "abbr"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "role"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.bigint "district_id"
    t.bigint "state_id"
    t.index ["district_id"], name: "index_users_on_district_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["state_id"], name: "index_users_on_state_id"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a further association into state:

```
has_many :cases, through: :districts
```

Rather than finding your state in the view, you should do that in the controller and pass it to the view in an instance variable:

```
@state = State.find(params[:id])
```

I've assumed you're using a show action here rather than manually coding the state ID for some reason.

You can then do something like this:

```
@state.cases.where(diagnoses: { id: @diagnosis.id }).count
```

Or if you prefer, you can skip the `.id` on @diagnosis:

```
@state.cases.where(diagnoses: { id: @diagnosis }).count
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if I can find my state in the controller. This is my diagnosis_controller:

`class Rki::DiagnosesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :current_user_rki?

  def current_user_rki?
    return if current_user.role == 'rki'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def index
    @diagnoses = Diagnosis.all
  end

  def cases
    #Alle Fälle zur Auswahl einer Diagnose
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.includes(:cases).find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

end`

That's why I were trying to find the state in my view.

Comment: And I don't want to find the state by it's params. It is static. I just want show the total amount for this specific state.

Comment: It doesn't sound like I can help you with your problem then.

Comment: Oh you did helped me! I added the further association into state. 
I didn't mean to appear ungrateful. Thank you for your answer! :)